# Concurrent use of JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean

Tags: java, web-services, spring, concurrency, endpoint

I'm using `JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean` (Spring 3.1.2) to access a remote web service. In the documentation I can't find anything on concurrent usage of the `JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean`. Is it allowed to use it concurrently with from threads? And if so, is it possible to dynamically change the enpoint address so that different threads can use a different endpoint for the same `JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About concurrently using you can see:
[JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.setExecutor(java.util.concurrent.Executor)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/remoting/jaxws/LocalJaxWsServiceFactory.html#setExecutor%28java.util.concurrent.Executor%29)
and [JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.setTaskExecutor(org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/remoting/jaxws/LocalJaxWsServiceFactory.html#setTaskExecutor%28org.springframework.core.task.TaskExecutor%29)

And also exist method [JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean.setWsdlDocumentUrl(String)](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/remoting/jaxws/LocalJaxWsServiceFactory.html#setWsdlDocumentUrl%28java.net.URL%29) but it isn't thread-save