# JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean and thread-safety?

Tags: java, spring, web-services, spring-ws, spring-remoting

We use `JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean` for accessing easily SOAP webservices. We have a specific service class annotated with the `@Service` from Spring which gets injected with this service proxy and which will be used in a controller.

What happens if there are concurrent requests? Is `JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean` thread safe?  Are there any performance considerations which should be taken into account (for example according to http connections, etc.)?

I have found this post here:
[Concurrent use of JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783286/concurrent-use-of-jaxwsportproxyfactorybean) but it did not answered my questions.

And here is also a very old similar question in the Spring forum, but without any answer :):
http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web-services/114532-jaxwsportproxyfactorybean-what´s-about-thread-safe-and-performance

Hope someone can help here and explain it a bit in more detail.

Thanks for your support!

Comment: The `JaxWsPortProxyFactoryBean` is only used once to create the JAX-WS service. After that it doesn't do anything anymore. After creating it depends on your jax-ws implementation if it is thread-safe or not.

Comment: ok, thanks. What about fine-tunning the connection pooling?

Comment: Again it doesn't matter, it is a `FactoryBean` that is only used one time at startup after that it is done and out of the picture.